# How to fix getters returning 'null' in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I wrote some code that is used to help visualize a percentage with a custom painter, but sometimes the percent is too small for it to display properly, so I decided to make a getter that conveniently returns a value which will be put into the painter.

I tried, as you can see in the provided code, to do a check that checks to see if the data has not yet loaded, and returns '0%', which should have worked.

```dart
double get winPercent {
    var initalValue = _stats.winPercent.isNotEmpty ? _stats.winPercent : '0%';
    var calculateWinPrcnt = (double.parse(
          initalValue.substring(0, _stats.winPercent.length - 1),
        ) /
        100);

    if (calculateWinPrcnt < 5) {
      return 0.05;
    }
    return calculateWinPrcnt;
  }
```

The getter should return '0%' if there is no data from the API yet, but I still get an error that the output is null

```
The getter 'winPercent' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: winPercent
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The getter 'winPercent' was called on null." means that `_stats` is probably null. You can do this:

```
double get winPercent {
  // check for nulls
  final initialValue = (_stats?.winPercent?.isNotEmpty ?? false) ? _stats.winPercent : '0%';
  final value = initialValue.substring(0, initialValue.length - 1);
  final winPrcnt = (double.parse(value) / 100);

  if (winPrcnt < 0.05) {
    return 0.05;
  }
  return winPrcnt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var _stats;

if(_stats==null){

_stats = className();

}
```

The Problem here is with The Object that the WinPercent is called On which is null  Try initalizing the _stats before Api is Called `var _stats = YourModelClassName()` And After Apis response is Fetched You Can Assign That Response Model Object to _stats.